# Look up where package came from

Tags: package

My .emacs file includes a line I presumably added ages ago

```
(require 'some-random-package)
```

I haven't actually been able to learn anything about the package.

My `load-path` is quite complicated (it takes up about a screenful) so a manual solution digging through the load path isn't ideal.

I'm aware emacs' rules for loading a package are to look through the directories in the load path for foo.elc and foo. How can I find where the package came from?

Comment: How about?:  `locate-library` [to see the path] or `find-library` [to open the library in a buffer]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to visit file containing source code for a given function?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10123/how-to-visit-file-containing-source-code-for-a-given-function). As explained in [this solution](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10126/115) to that question, using the `elisp-slime-nav` package, simply put the point over `some-random-package` in that `require` statement and hit `M-.`

Comment: Also, if your installed packages exist on one of the repositories like Melpa or GNU Elpa, then you don't have to manually populate `load-path`; make use of the package manager to install packages and do `(package-initialize)`. [Package installation how-to from Xah Lee's blog](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html).

Comment: @lawlist You should post your comment as an answer. I don't think this question is a real duplicate of [How to visit file containing source code for a given function?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10123/504) as it focuses on *packages* instead of functions; also, OP seems to be more interested in seeing the *path* than actually jumping to the library.

Answer (score 3):

There are two built-in *interactive* functions to help a user track down a library that is within the `load-path` -- i.e., `locate-library` [*to see the path*] and `find-library` [*to open the library in a buffer*].

---

**M-x locate-library**

```
locate-library is an interactive compiled Lisp function in 'subr.el'.

(locate-library LIBRARY &optional NOSUFFIX PATH INTERACTIVE-CALL)

Show the precise file name of Emacs library LIBRARY.
LIBRARY should be a relative file name of the library, a string.
It can omit the suffix (a.k.a. file-name extension) if NOSUFFIX is
nil (which is the default, see below).
This command searches the directories in 'load-path' like 'M-x load-library'
to find the file that 'M-x load-library RET LIBRARY RET' would load.
Optional second arg NOSUFFIX non-nil means don't add suffixes 'load-suffixes'
to the specified name LIBRARY.

If the optional third arg PATH is specified, that list of directories
is used instead of 'load-path'.

When called from a program, the file name is normally returned as a
string.  When run interactively, the argument INTERACTIVE-CALL is t,
and the file name is displayed in the echo area.
```

---

**M-x find-library**

```
find-library is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
'find-func.el'.

(find-library LIBRARY)

Find the Emacs Lisp source of LIBRARY.
LIBRARY should be a string (the name of the library).
```